# Argument of type 'Element[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'

const Ques = (Props:JSX.Element) => {
    return (
        <Fragment>{Props}</Fragment>
    );
}
const ListName = ["Gus","Thekla","Anna","Sophia"].map((Name)=> <div>{Name}</div>)
Ques(ListName)
```

in line `Ques(ListName)`
I get this error.

> Argument of type 'Element[]' is not assignable to parameter of type > > 
>   'Element'.
>    Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': > type, props, key

Comment: It looks like you are trying to assign an array to a non-array element?

Comment: What is JSX in the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing an array of JSX.Element,

```
const Ques = (Props:JSX.Element[]) => {
    return (
        <Fragment>{Props}</Fragment>
    );
}
const ListName = ["Gus","Thekla","Anna","Sophia"].map((Name)=> <div>{Name}</div>)
Ques(ListName)
```

When you run this code, you’ll be given a warning that a key should be provided for list items. A “key” is a special string attribute you need to include when creating lists of elements.

I would write like this

```
const Ques = (Props:JSX.Element[]) => {
    return (
        <Fragment>{Props}</Fragment>
    );
}
const ListName = ["Gus","Thekla","Anna","Sophia"].map((Name,nameindex)=> <div key={`${Name}${nameindex/10}`}>{Name}</div>)
Ques(ListName)
```

You can read about the keys here [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).